# I am unable to add an element to a list? UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java, list, object, addition, abstract

This one list object is biting me in the butt..

Any time I try to add an element to it, it produces this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
        at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:148)
        at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:108)
```

The line producing the error is insignificant, but here it is anyways:

```
AdventureLobbies.players.add(args[0].toLowerCase());
```

Should I not be accessing it statically?

Actual declaration of variable:

`AdventureLobbies.players = Arrays.asList(rs.getString("players").toLowerCase().split(","));`

Any ideas? Can't find anything on Google that's worthwhile.

Comment: Please show us the declaration for `AdventureLobbies.players`.

Comment: I second @KirkWoll's suggestion.  I wouldn't be surprised if `AdventureLobbies.players` is an immutable list, which might have been returned from [Collections.unmodifiableList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList(java.util.List)) or another method that accomplishes the same thing.

Comment: Agreed with both previous comments - without us knowing the type of the object (hence why we need to see the declaration, or the method call where you got this list), it's hard to know why exactly why this is happening, though immutable list is a good educated guess.

Comment: @KirkWoll `AdventureLobbies.players = Arrays.asList(rs.getString("players").toLowerCase().split(","));`

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Arrays.asList() will give you back an unmodifiable list, and that is why your add is failing.  Try creating the list with:

```
AdventureLobbies.players = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(rs.getString("players").toLowerCase().split(",")));
```

Comment: Great Answer Thank You.

Answer (score 5):

The java docs say 
    `asList`
    `@SafeVarargs`
    `public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a)`
"Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array"

Your list is fixed size, meaning it cannot grow or shrink and so when you call add, it throws an unsupported operation exception

Answer (score 0):

This exception is very familiar with accessing objects that will not permit the access according to java language rules like accessing immutable objects, for that reason instantiate it in the following way instead:

```
AdventureLobbies.players = new ArrayList(Arrays.
asList(rs.getString("players").toLowerCase().split(","))); // Perfectly done
```